# QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Errors:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3  
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active  
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

I made a small example that reproduces this error, but it doesn't reproduce the exact nature of the error. In the original code I have these QGraphicsSimpleTextItems (MyCallout) act as attachments to a QGraphicsItem that never moves, and never changes position; instead it has an image that I redraw that looks like a loading bar. The text item is meant to follow and move up or down according to the percentage of that bar. If I scroll my view down so the text item is no longer visible and then scroll back up, I see artefacts. Specifically, I see that my QGraphicsLineItem used in MyCallout has an additional copy slightly above/below the original, and the text portion of MyCallout has disappeared. When I scroll left or right and then back is when I see these QPainter errors. This small example has these errors as soon as they are created and added to the scene and when scrolling up or down, but the artefact issue is much less pronounced.

Source for small compilable example:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindowtest.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    MainWindow  mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
    int rc = app.exec();
    printf("%d\n",rc);
    return 0;
}
```

mainwindowtest.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainwindowtest.h"
#include "myviewtest.h"
#include "myscenetest.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(){
    scene = new MyScene(this);
    QSize size2=QSize(100000,6000);
    view = new MyView(scene,size2);
    setCentralWidget(view); 

}
```

mainwindowtest.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QListView>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QLayout>
class MyView;
class MyScene;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public: 
        MainWindow();
    protected:

    private slots:
    signals:

    private:
    MyView *view;
        QWidget * window;
        MyScene * scene;

};
#endif
```

mycallouttest.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mycallouttest.h"
#include "myscenetest.h"

MyCallout::MyCallout (QGraphicsItem* parent) : QGraphicsSimpleTextItem (parent) {
    setZValue(100);
    setText(QString("0:"));
    setBrush(QColor("violet"));
    _shadow = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
    _shadow->setOffset(-boundingRect().x()+1.05,-boundingRect().y()+1.05);
    _shadow->setBlurRadius(0);
    _shadow->setColor("black");
    setGraphicsEffect(_shadow);     
    _line.setParentItem(this);
    _line.setLine(4,boundingRect().height()+18,14,boundingRect().height()-3);
    _line.setZValue(90);
    _line.setPen(QColor("violet"));
    hide();
}

void MyCallout::setTextTo(const QString & text){
    QString a=this->text();
    int i = this->text().indexOf(":");
    if(i>0){
        a.remove(i+1,a.size());
        a.append(text);
        setText(a);
    }else{
        printf("warning: callout text with no ':'\n");
    }
}

void MyCallout::position(int col,int value){

    printf("position\n");
    QString label;
    QString a=text();
    int i = text().indexOf(":");
    if(i>0){
        a.remove(0,i);
        a.prepend(QString(QString("%1").arg(value)));
    }else{
        a=QString(QString("%1:").arg(value));
    }
    setText(a);
    setPos((col+1)*7, (MAX_ROW-value-3)*7);
    prepareGeometryChange();
    show();
    update();
}

QRectF MyCallout::boundingRect() const{
    return QGraphicsSimpleTextItem::boundingRect();

}
```

mycallouttest.h

```
#ifndef MY_CALLOUT_H
#define MY_CALLOUT_H
#include <QGraphicsSimpleTextItem>
class QGraphicsLineItem;
class QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
class MyCallout :public QGraphicsSimpleTextItem {
    //Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyCallout(QGraphicsItem * parent =0);

        void position(int col,int value);
        void setTextTo(const QString & text);

        QRectF boundingRect() const;
    protected:
        QGraphicsLineItem   _line;
        QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * _shadow;

};
#endif
```

myscenetest.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "myscenetest.h"
#include "mainwindowtest.h"
#include "mycallouttest.cpp"
MyScene::MyScene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent){
    setSceneRect(0,0,MAX_COL*11,MAX_ROW*11);
   QGraphicsScene::setBackgroundBrush (QColor(173,216,230));
    MyCallout *c;
        for(int i=1;i<=MAX_COL;++i){     
        c=new MyCallout;
        c->position(i,50);
        addItem(c);
    }
}
```

myscenetest.h

```
#ifndef MY_SCENE_H
#define MY_SCENE_H
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QList>
#include "myviewtest.h"
#define MAX_ROW 90
#define MAX_COL 360
class MyView;
class MyScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyScene(QObject * parent =0);
    public slots:

    signals:
    private:

};
#endif
```

myviewtest.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "myviewtest.h"
MyView::MyView(QGraphicsScene * scene,QSize &size,QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(scene,parent){

    setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    setDragMode(RubberBandDrag);
    setMouseTracking(true);
    setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
    _zoom_level=0;
    _size=size;
}
const QSize MyView::sizeHint(){
    return _size;
}
void MyView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event){
    if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier){
         if(event->delta() > 0){
            zoomIn();
            centerOn(mapToScene(event->pos()));
            _zoom_level--;
            emit updateZoom();
         } else {
            zoomOut();
            centerOn(mapToScene(event->pos()));
            _zoom_level++;
            emit updateZoom();
         }
    }else{
        QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);
    }
}
```

myviewtest.h

```
#ifndef MY_VIEW_H
#define MY_VIEW_H
#include <QGraphicsView>  
class MyView : public QGraphicsView {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyView(QGraphicsScene * scene,QSize &size,QWidget *parent = NULL);

        virtual const QSize sizeHint();
    public slots:
        void zoomIn(){ scale(1.1,1.1);};
        void zoomOut(){ scale(1/1.1,1/1.1);};
        void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event);
    signals:
        void updateZoom();      
    protected:
        int _zoom_level;
        QSize _size;
};
#endif
```

Comment: I don't see any errors. Tested in Qt 4.8 and 5.1.

Comment: I think I'm using 4.6.2 and did you try zooming in (ctrl+wheelForward) and moving the scroll bars so the text items are no longer visible and then scrolling back? After doing that if you drag the mouse over the text items it will erase small parts of them.